# How to generate the actual results of an IRF() function in python?

Tags: python, var, statsmodels

I am unable to generate the actual underlying values of the IRFs. See code of a simple VAR model.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa as sm
model = VAR(df_differenced.astype(float))
results = model.fit()
irf = results.irf(10)
```

I can generate the resulting IRF plots just fine with this code:

```
irf.plot(orth=False)
```

But, I can't generate the underlying values. I'd like to do so to have precise figures. Visually interpreting IRFs is not that accurate. Using the summary() did not provide me this information.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `irfs` property or `cum_effects` (cumulative irf). `results.irf` returns an [`IRAnalysis` object](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.irf.IRAnalysis.html). The documentation is below the standard where it should be.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa as sm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((300,3)))
model = VAR(df)
results = model.fit()
irf = results.irf(10)
print(irf.irfs)
print(irf.cum_effects)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the actual answer.
You can type

```
results.irf(10)
```

or try

```
results.impulse_responses(10)
```

It will give you a table with the actual point estimates from the VAR